# dynamically value inside javascript src url

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I'd like to put a javascript variable value dynamically inside to a script src url.

```
<head runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var id = $("[id$='hfProductIdList']").val();
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://test/tr.aspx?orderid=id">
 </script>    
</head>
```

If there is a way to set up these value dynamicly It would be great for me.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? if you want to send file to server side script (in this case asp) use ajax. you are giving asp page as source where it is expected js (because you use type = javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
var id = $("[id$='hfProductIdList']").val();
$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test/tr.aspx?orderid=' + id + '" />');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append it using pure javasript;

```
var id = $("[id$='hfProductIdList']").val();
var jsElem = window.document.createElement('script');
jsElem.src = 'https://test/tr.aspx?orderid=' + id;
jsElem.type = 'text/javascript';
$('head').append(jsElem);
```

Also it might be better idea to append it to body rahter than head, but it's not a subject of your question.